# How to get Name-property from 'Class' by ClassId from 'Table1' using LinQ?

Tags: c#, linq, asp.net-mvc-4

I have 2 table in db.  First table its all description, second table description one partial in the first table.Its look like:

```
+----------+    +----------+
I  Table1  I    I  Class   I
+----------+    +----------+
I  Id      I    I  Id      I
I  ClassId I <- I  Name    I
+----------+    +----------+
```

Main table its table1.Connection tables are available.

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult RoomFound(int className, FormCollection collection)
{
    var example = db.table1.Where(p => p.ClassId == className);
    ViewBag.Ex = example.ToList();
}
```

And now, when i create View and show the result, it shows me ClassId like numbers, but i want to see string format from table2. How can i connect ties from  table2 (Class) in my main table (table1).

Comment: Assuming you are using Entity Framework, you should have navigation property in your Table1 definition for accessing corresponding Class. You can then this property to get the name. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/jj713564.aspx

Comment: If you want to get the Name from Class based on ClassId, which I assume is the same as Id from Class. Why go through Table1 at all?

Comment: Hi and Welcome to SO. Please next time use a short description of your problem/question as title and not tags.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming `className` is in fact a `ClassId` then you have no need to even query the `Table1` table, just query the `Class` table directly i.e.

```
ViewBag.Ex = db.Class.Where(p => p.Id == className).Select(p => p.Name).ToList();
```

However, I will point out there is a clear relationship here between `Table1` and `Class` therefore it's generally a good idea to define this at DB level and have this carried through to your ORM model which automatically gives you *navigation* properties e.g.

```
var t = db.table1.Where(p => p.ClassId == className);
ViewBag.Ex = t.Select(p => p.Class.Name).ToList();
```

Like I said though, it doesn't look like you even need to query the `Table1` table at all here.